# how to insert value in multiple text box in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This is my java code

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class SetExchange {
public void Execute(String CountryName, String value)
{
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("SET")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("EXCHANGE RATE")).click();
       //LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("new_Afghanistan_AFN")).sendKeys(value);
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@maxlength='4']")).sendKeys(value);
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='SET']")).click();

}

}
```

this is my html

```
<div style="display: table-cell;width:270px" name="cell">
<input id="new_Afghanistan_AFN" type="text" maxlength="4">
<input type="button" value="SET"   onclick="setExchangeRate('Afghanistan','AFN')" name="save">
<div id="msg_Afghanistan_AFN"></div>
</div>
```

There are more than 100 textbox in my webpage and same number of button
  in front of textbox.I want to insert value in all the 100 textbox
sequentially and similarly click on button.But from the above code I am able to insert the value in single text box and similarly click on single button.
   so my question is how to insert value into all text box and click on  multiple button.Each text box is having different id but if I use findelement(By.id)
 then the code will be too much longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all buttons and textboxes are surrounded by the same div, you can search for these like:

```
List<WebElement> divs = LaunchApplication.driver.findElements(By.name("cell"));
```

Note that the findElements returns all elements which match the criteria.

Then you can loop through the results like this:

```
for(WebElement elem: divs){
    elem.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type=text]")).sendKeys("YOUR KEYS TO SEND");
    elem.findElement(By.cssSelector("[type=button]")).click();
}
```

this will select first the textfield and then the button of each div with name cell. Maybe you need to check if other divs are called "cell" which are not holding these elements.

If you don't know `CssSelectors` these will match an Attribute Text. For more info look here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Another way would be to read in / or create the list of IDs and then get the elements in a loop.

Does this help you, if not please feel free to comment

Comment: By using above code I am getting an error that "unable to locate element by xpath".

Comment: the error tels you that you are trying to locate an element by xpath, in my code example there is no `By.xpath` is it possible that the error is in another line of your code, or did you write something wrong ?

Comment: I also use by.css_selector but same error i am getting.

Comment: locate element is the problem.may be i am not selecting the correct element.

Comment: xpath and css selector both are throwing an error and also can you tell me the another way. like by id.

Comment: do you understand the difference between the selectors? And in which line of my code your error is thrown?????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77892/discussion-between-dude-and-abnimkar).